# My tiling window manager is crashing with ediff-mode window creation. How to fix it?

Tags: window, ediff

I am using Material Shell which is a tiling window manager created as an extension of GNOME Desktop Environment.

After an interactive rebase in Magit, a merge conflict happened. Thus, to fix it, I pressed `e` on the problematic file. `e` is bound to `eDiff`.

Unfortunately, Emacs gets messy because `eDiff` creates a new window which is not properly handled by the tilling window manager.

How to solve this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```lisp
(setq ediff-window-setup-function 'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
```

The doc string of the variable `ediff-window-setup-function` (which can be viewed in Emacs with `C-h v ediff-window-setup-function`) says:

```
Ediff provides a choice of three functions:
 (1) `ediff-setup-windows-multiframe', which sets the control panel
     in a separate frame.
 (2) `ediff-setup-windows-plain', which does everything in one frame
 (3) `ediff-setup-windows-default' (the default), which does (1)
     on a graphical display and (2) on a text terminal.
```

so the `plain` choice does not create a new frame.

Comment: It's great that you solve the problems that you encounter and that you actually document the problem and its solution, but might I suggest a little more detail in the answer? What exactly does the expression you suggest do? I know what it does, but remember you are writing for future (and quite possibly naive) users who would find that extra snippet of detail enlightening.

Comment: This is a free to use q&a website. There is no basis to ask people to improve their work

Comment: Thanks for the compliment and the feedback, @NickD. I will try to improve! When I did this, I was in a hurry with a deadline from work. You are right, I could have provided more details.

Comment: @user31313 Of course it's legitimate to ask for improvements, if you do so courteously, as NickD infallibly does (and has, to me, to my benefit). This is not only a free-to-use q&a website, it's a collaborative one.

Comment: Infallibly? No (as @PedroDelfino can attest, I've had my bad moments), but improvements can happen not only to questions/answers but also to the people who ask/answer/comment on them. I hope that is the case with me. And Phil's point about the website being a collaborative work-in-progress is indeed very pertinent: we all hope (I hope:-) ) that anything we do on this site will help somebody in the future, as well as the person who asked the question. So collaborative, incremental improvement to answers (and sometimes to questions) is something that happens all the time.